# Document is undefined Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this code in my html to trigger a file input when this div is clicked. Currently I get an error that document is undefined, but when I add a breakpoint and watch for the document variable I see that it is infact defined at the time this html runs. I'm using the angular framework.

```
  <input id="file-input" type="file" name="name" style="display: none;" />
  <div class="csvBox" id="csvBox" (click)="document.getElementById('file-input').click();">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template have access only to component properties. `document` is not one.

Moreover, you should never use `document.getElementById` with Angular. You can use template variable like this:

```html
<input #fileInput type="file" name="name" style="display: none;" />
<div class="csvBox" id="csvBox" (click)="fileInput.click()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to import document from angular.

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Component()
 export class MyService {
 constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}
}
```